# Как создать проект Gradle Android Application в IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Не могу разобраться, как создать проект Gradle Android Application.

Comment: Зачем? Чем Android Studio не устраивает? Оно удобнее будет чем ванильная идея

Comment: не знаю захотел попробовать а он Gradle поддерживает?

Comment: В последний раз как смотрел поддерживал. Правда для чистой явы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA полностью поддерживает Android-разработку и включает в свою дефолтную поставку все плагины, разработанные Google для Android Studio: Android Support и Gradle.

Идешь: `File -> New -> Project ...`

Появляется следующее окно:

[image: screen]

нажимаешь `next` и далее следуешь указаниям мастера.

Если в окне New Project нет пунктов, как на скриншоте, то вам необходимо самостоятельно подключить из репозитория IDEA вышеупомянутые плагины: Android Support и Gradle.

PS: Если вас интересует исключительно android-разработка, то лучшим решением будет использовать гугловский форк IntelliJ IDEA - [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). Это практически та же IDE, но в нее по умолчанию не включено множество плагинов "большой" IDEA, которые не нужны для android-разработки.

IDEA - универсальная среда разработки для многих платформ, Android Studio заточена исключительно под android-разработку. В остальном это два сопоставимых (даже идентичных) продукта.
Стоит заметить, что подключая или отключая плагины из IDEA можно сделать Android Studio, а из Android Studio - IDEA Community